# If statement returning not equal to 0 when value equals 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable, Diff as a double. (values are a sample from my Workbook)

```
Dim Diff As Double
Sheets(Sheet1).Activate
Diff = 4382.98-4117.34-265.64
```

Values for calculating Diff come from cells formatted as numbers.
I then use Diff as an argument in an if statement.

```
If Diff <> 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(A2).Value = 265.64 + Diff
End If
```

Diff should equal 0, but the if statement is proceeding as if the condition is true. I have similar if statements that do not have problems like this. Do I need to format my values differently?

Edit: Had 43892.98 instead of 4382.98
Edit2: Had 256.64 instead of 265.64

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Your Diff also does not equal 0 here, floating point math issues aside.

Comment: I tried rounding Diff   'Round(43892.98-4117.34-256.64+0.000001,2)' and still have the error (the extra 0.0000001 is to avoid Banker's rounding).

Comment: Should be 4382.98, not 43892.98.

Comment: Yeah, that equals `8.99999999999943`.  Not zero.

Comment: Wow, I'm having issues typing. It should also be 265.64, not 256.64. I've learned a valuable lesson in proofreading.

Comment: And that also is not zero, it is `-5.6843418860808E-13`.  Try adding a `Debug.Print Diff` statement right before your IF statement.

Comment: To make a very long story short, try following the link that Jacob H posted and reading that.  The bottom line is, unless you keep everything in integer values, ***you should never test floating-point values for equality!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Never, NEVER, **NE-VER compare doubles on equity!** (vars of floating point type)
   Let even just in the mind only - never...
   And you do right - your compare is "<>" - and you got the right result.
2. Currency is INTEGER type, i.e. not-floating point var.

   - values, exceeded 4 digits after point, are rounding internally;
   - compare on equity is correct.
     .

Answer (score 0):

I stored Diff As Currency instead of Double and the issue cleared up.